# mvn appengine:run fails to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:run mvn appengine:deploy works fine

Tags: java, maven, gcloud

I am following the instructions from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/static-content I can deploy my changes and check them using gcloud app browse, but I cannot make the local development environment work.

Running mvn appengine:run -DskipTests returns the following error, and trying mvn package clean beforehand doesn't change it

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The project mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp:groceryapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp:groceryapp >--------------
[INFO] Building groceryapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:run (default-cli) @ groceryapp ---
Feb 26, 2020 3:28:56 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.DevAppServerRunner run
INFO: submitting command: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/13.0.2+8_2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xdebug -Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=3 -Duse_jetty9_runtime=true -D--enable_all_permissions=true -Dappengine.sdk.root=/Users/kn/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java -cp /Users/kn/Library/Application Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --allow_remote_shutdown --disable_update_check --no_java_agent /Users/kn/Documents/private/musical-funicular/groceryapp/target/groceryapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory (file:/Users/kn/Library/Application%20Support/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/java/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar) to method java.net.URL.getURLStreamHandler(java.lang.String)
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.appengine.tools.development.StreamHandlerFactory
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[INFO] GCLOUD: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create a DevAppServer
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:369)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:301)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:383)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:124)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:354)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 5 more
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.SocksSocketImpl.<init>()
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevSocketImplFactory.<clinit>(DevSocketImplFactory.java:76)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 12 more
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.SocksSocketImpl.<init>()
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevSocketImplFactory.<clinit>(DevSocketImplFactory.java:72)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 12 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.892 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-26T15:28:57+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:run (default-cli) on project groceryapp: Failed to run devappserver: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Kristians-MacBook-Air:groceryapp kn$
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>groceryapp</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <!-- uncomment if you wish to set your project here project- gcloud is used otherwise -->
    <!-- <app.deploy.project>enduring-trees-259812</app.deploy.project> -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.5</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.78</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.78</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.78</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.78</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
      <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <project>enduring-trees-259812</project>
          <version>1</version>
            <jvmFlags>
              <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
              <jvmFlag>-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=3</jvmFlag>
            </jvmFlags>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
              <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api</exclude>
            <exclude>com.google.guava:guava</exclude> <!-- avoid android version -->
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.5</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
                <requirePluginVersions>
                   <message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message>
                   <banLatest>true</banLatest>
                   <banRelease>true</banRelease>
                   <phases>clean,deploy,verify,appengine:run,appengine:deploy,appengine:update,appengine:devappaserver,site</phases>
                </requirePluginVersions>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
    <static-files>
      <include path="/**.html"></include>
    </static-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

`mvn clean install -U` has been run

Comment: Can you attach your `pom.xml` and your `appengine-web.xml` file so I can see if the issue is because of the dependencies or something wrong on the configuration files.

But in the meantime you could try running this command:

`mvn clean install -U`

This command re-downloads all the dependencies in case something failed or was not downloaded properly previously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sneacsu both files now added

Comment: the appengine-web.xml is missing and did you try running the `mvn clean install -U` command?

Comment: mvn clean install -U has been run now, everything went well. File has been added

Comment: Did you try `mvn appengine:run` after doing `mvn clean install -U`.

I cannot see anything wrong with your configuration file.

Comment: I just ran mvn appengine:run now but I still get `Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run failed: Non zero exit: 1`

Comment: Can you try this following command? Maybe you did not package first so the WAR is not created for the application to run: `mvn package appengine:run`

Comment: I didn't run package first, so I have tried `mvn clean install -U` and then `mvn package appengine:run` but I still get `Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:run failed: Non zero exit: 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203525/discussion-between-sneacsu-and-kristian-nissen).

Comment: Try to change version of  the plugin `appengine-maven-plugin` and check again.

Comment: @invzbl3 which version would you recommend? I am running the version listed here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin

Comment: Any other releases from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/releases). Try also to play (update/roll back versions) with other dependencies at the same time in your project. Moreover, check if specific plugins can be cause of error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same build error because of using unmatched JDK version.
Check your JDK version with "java -version". Probably you should use Java8(Java1.8) instead of Open JDK13.

Comment: Hi, thanks.
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

And thank you for commenting : )

Answer (score 0):

After researching many resources, I finally got the answer, you need to update the Python version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJMa.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).